# Trying to print user inputs [edited]

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to print user inputs to webpage comment section but don't know what do in place value ? It's like autofill comment section

```
 <input id="fname" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Enter name" />
<input id="pageurl" placeholder="Paste here url"    type="url" size="30" />

<button class="button1" onclick="eatFood();"> <b>Submit</b> </button>

<script type="text/javaScript">
function eatFood(){
var url =document.getElementById("pageurl").value;`

window.open(url ,"msgwindow")
document.getElementById('  ').value = " what_i_Do_here";
     }</Script>
```

Comment: It seems you have several misunderstandings regarding some fundamental concepts in Javascript. I'd recommend building the requisite foundational skills before continuing any further.

Comment: Beacause I recently learnt JavaScript and trying to make autofill tool

Answer (score -1):

### Hi "Sagg" Welcome to Stackoverflow

What i understood from your question you want auto filled valued from your input"Enter Name" So here is solution for that just you can achieve that , if this is not the case please define that what exactly you want Your question is too much ambiguous

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>


     <input id="fname" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Enter name" />
     <br>

    <button class="button1" onclick="eatFood();"> <b>Submit</b> </button>
    <br><br>
      <input id="fnameExample" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Examaple auto fill" />


    <script>
    function eatFood(){
    var url =document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById('fnameExample').value = (url+'  '+"auto filled On Submit");
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks you got it what I want and appreciate  your efforts

Comment: You are welcome "Sagg" Please accept answer and up vote it :-)